# an adjective that makes condition "unbreakable"

Tags: word-request, adjectives

I need an adjective that, when applied to the word "condition", makes that condition "unbreakable".
In the text below the word "necessary" is used. Is there a better adjective in English for such case?

> Somehow it has become a rule with time that anyone in our group who is
> stating a problem that he or she assumes to be taking place in our
> company must also provide at least one way of solving it. But why? Why
> should having a ready solution be a **necessary** condition for
> stating a problem? Anyone must feel free to bring up a problem even
> without having any idea how to solve it. In fact, if you already know
> how to fix a problem, then it doesn't look like a problem to you and you don't  really feel the need to state it. However, the very
> reason why someone would want to state a problem at the meeting is
> because they don't know the solution while other members may.

Comment: You frequently see the phrase "[requisite](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/requisite) condition," although some people think that sounds a bit like legalese.

Comment: I like "necessary condition", perhaps because it speaks to my Maths background. You could perhaps change it to "requirement".

Comment: I think the word "necessary" does the job. "Indispensable" might be more emphatic, but logically it's the same.

Comment: In almost all contexts, ***precondition*** means exactly the same as ***necessary condition, fundamental / unbreakable requirement***.

Comment: You're probably looking for the word *requirement*.

Answer (score 0):

[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=condition+meaning&oq=condition&aqs=chrome.0.35i39j69i57j69i60l3.3858j1j7&client=ms-android-samsung-gj-rev1&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) defines:

> condition
> /kənˈdɪʃ(ə)n/
>
> a situation that **must** exist before something else is possible or permitted.
>
> Similar:
> stipulation constraint prerequisite precondition requirement rule term specification provision proviso qualification necessity essential demand restriction

(emphasis mine)

Some of the similar words listed include 'necessity'.  We hence should not repeat the adjective form.

'Condition' alone should do the job.

Comment: Please quote (using ">") what you copy-paste from other sources.

Comment: There is a distinction between a necessary condition and a sufficient condition. The use of the adjective is needed to distinguish between them. This answer is wrong.

Comment: I don't see anything in the OP that would make the *necessary / sufficient condition* distinction relevant. A "sufficient" condition is simply a special case of "necessary" condition that implies *there are no **other** necessary conditions* (so long as that single condition is true, whatever logically follows from it will *definitely* also be true).

Comment: "Necessary" and "sufficient" may be used rather effectively as synonyms, eg "necessary supplies", "sufficient supplies"

Answer (score 0):

The word "contingent" may be used to mean "dependent" and either word may be used. In this example "why is it a contingent condition to" means "why is it a necessary condition to". Another word that may be very successful is "requisite", which means "required", and either may be used effectively. Another alternative is "indispensable".

There are also some single-word substitutes for "necessary condition", such as "prerequisite", "precondition" or "necessity".